# How to update a db table field with a looping sequence of numbers (2-4)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Been puzzling on this one for a few hours, scoured google and nothing ..

I'm trying to update a SQL Server table with a looping sequence of numbers (2,3,4) in each row ..

```
update table 
set fieldname = (*black magic*) 
where otherfieldname = something
```

So result would be

```
other fields|2|other fields|
other fields|3|other fields|
other fields|4|other fields|
other fields|2|other fields|
other fields|3|other fields|
other fields|4|other fields|
other fields|2|other fields|
other fields|3|other fields|
```

Any ideas welcome!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number to generate an ascending sequential number. Take mod 3 of that to get a number between 0 and 2 then add 2 to that to make it between 2 and 4.

```
WITH T 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                ( ROW_NUMBER() 
                    OVER ( ORDER BY @@SPID) % 3 ) + 2 AS X 
         FROM   YourTable) 
UPDATE T 
SET    YourCol = X
```

Answer (score 0):

Ntile(limit) will provide an even distribution of numbers to your table. Where 'limit' is how many distinct values there should be. Just add 1 for your offset.

```
with t1 as (
select *, blackMagic = ntile(3) over(order by newid()) + 1
from someTable
)
update t1
set fieldname = blackMagic
```

Comment: I'm not on a PC at the moment to test but I imagine the plan for this will be less efficient than the one in my answer because of the sort. Also I can't remember if NTile will add a common sub expression spool.

Comment: Hmm... i don't know that there would be much of a difference between them, they are both windowed functions that need to take in the entire result set. May be worth testing though, one could easily replace 'newid()' with '@@spid' and test performance. It'd be interesting to see results on a large table.

Comment: Yes. Replacing with @@spid would avoid the sort. I think NTile adds a spool though that wouldn't be present in the row number version (though the plan may still have a spool for Halloween protection in some circumstances)